# JavaFx "Locking" Scrollpane Position

Tags: java, javafx

My app has a scrollpane with a big content in it.

The app also has a fullscreen toggle button.

I am attempting to have functionality that the ScrollPane's content does not move ***at all***, when I switch between fullscreen and windowed mode.

I first attempted to do some calculations to translate the viewport.. but this feels kind of overkill.

So I thought I should somehow "lock" the ScrollPane, while I switch to fullscreen/windowed, and the "unlock" it again.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Added an example of the problem.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PositionExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setMinSize(3000, 3000);
        pane.setMaxSize(3000, 3000);
        pane.setPrefSize(3000, 3000);

        Label label = new Label("Double-click anywhere, and due to \nScrollPane's panning \"side-effect\" ,\nI don't move a bit (though I flicker once).\nTHIS is what I am after.\n\nHowever, press F11, and I will move!");
        label.setMouseTransparent(true);
        pane.getChildren().add(label);

        ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane(pane);

        pane.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                primaryStage.setFullScreen(!primaryStage.isFullScreen());
            }
        });

        // This is a curious side-effect! If I set the scroller pannable,
        // and do not consume the pressed-event, double-clicking 
        // positions the scrollpane so that the label does not move at all.
        // But how do I achieve this simple effect without setPannable?
        scroller.setPannable(true);

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            label.setLayoutX(pane.getWidth() / 2 - label.getWidth() / 2);
            label.setLayoutY(pane.getHeight() / 2 - label.getHeight() / 2);
            scroller.setVvalue(0.5);
            scroller.setHvalue(0.5);
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(scroller, 400, 400);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (KeyCode.F11.equals(e.getCode())) {
                primaryStage.setFullScreen(!primaryStage.isFullScreen());
            }
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Application#start` will executed in the JavaFX Application Thread. So there is no need for `Platform#runLater`

Comment: Actually there is since the label's size isn't known yet at that point.